# Cannot find prod.conf when using `$ start -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf`

Tags: java, scala, configuration, playframework, playframework-2.1

Previously, I was able to start play application using the relative path of prod.conf:

`$ start -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf`

However, after some changes, I am only able to start play using the absolute path of prod.conf:

`$ start -Dconfig.file=/opt/conf/prod.conf`

Has anyone seen this problem before?

Comment: I would guess prod.conf used to be in your classpath (eg: WEB-INF/classes) but no longer there.

Comment: Thanks @gerrytan! I did not use Tomcat/JBoss, so I don't have a WEB-INF directory.  Currently, I am running Play as standalone application.

Comment: A relative path starts calculating from the `conf` directory of the application.